# Kendo UI - Displaying images in a tooltip

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-template, kendo-tooltip

I have an issue with displaying images within a tooltip. Each Territory contains a Photo field. I'm trying to display a placeholder image if the Photo field is null.

Here's an idea of what I'm trying to achieve, tried it out but got errors. I'm pretty sure this template is syntactically incorrect:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="storeTerritory">
<div class="tooltipcontent">
    #for(var i = 0; i < Territories.length; i++){#
        #if (#=Photo# != 'null' && #=Photo# != '')  {#
            <img src="#=Territories[i].Photo#" alt="" />
        #} else{#
            <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/website-kit-2/600/547756-Cross-128.png" alt="" />
        #}#
    #}#
</div>
</script>
```

Here's a demo with a working tooltip (without the snippet above):
http://jsbin.com/iJunOsa/25/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `if` that you are enclosing `Photo` between `#=` and `#` but since the `if` is already surrounded by `#` you don't have to.

Next is that `Photo` is part of `Territories` elements, so (I think) you should be checking `Territories[i].Photo` for `null` and not just `Photo`.

The template should be:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="storeTerritory">
<div class="tooltipcontent">
    #for(var i = 0; i < Territories.length; i++){#
        #if (Territories[i].Photo != 'null' && Territories[i].Photo != '')  {#
            <img src="#=Territories[i].Photo#" alt="" />
        #} else{#
            <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/website-kit-2/600/547756-Cross-128.png" alt="" />
        #}#
    #}#
</div>
</script>
```

Check it here: http://jsbin.com/iJunOsa/32/

**EDIT** Following the comment it show that having multiple elements in `Territories` field and since each of them should use a different `Photo`, there is one additional problem that is identifying the photo to show.

The easies way is adding some information about the photo in the template that generates `Description` text that when `Tooltip` is shown, knows exactly which `Photo` to show.

What I mean is changing the template that you use for generating the `Description` to:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="territoriesTemplate">
#for(var i = 0; i < Territories.length; i++){#
    <a class="hasTooltip" data-photo="#= Territories[i].Photo #">#:Territories[i].TerritoryDescription#</a>&nbsp;<button class="info-btn">Info</button>
#}#
</script>
```

Where I added a `data-photo` element which value is the path to the photo then shown in the tooltip (i.e. add `data-photo="#= Territories[i].Photo #"` to the anchor `a`).

Then the code for generating the tooltip would be as simple as:

```
content: function (e) {
    // Get the template
    var template = kendo.template($("#storeTerritory").html());
    // Retrieve the photo from data and send it as argument to the template
    return template({ photo : $(e.target).data("photo")});
}
```

Finally, the new definition of the template is also pretty simple:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="storeTerritory">
<div class="tooltipcontent">
    #if (photo)  {#
        <img src="#=photo#" alt="" />
    #} else{#
        <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/website-kit-2/600/547756-Cross-128.png" alt="" />
    #}#
</div>
</script>
```

That simply checks if `photo` is defined and if so uses it, otherwise uses default value.

See it in action here : http://jsbin.com/iJunOsa/40/

Comment: Thanks! It works for the demo, but realized I'm having problems with my own datasource. Had to change it to `if (Territories[i].Photo != null)`, but it doesn't display the correct image even if the field is not null.

Comment: Right! you should not be asking for `'null'` but `null`. You might even consider checking for `if (Territories[i].Photo) ...` then it also covers if it is `undefined`.

Comment: What does it mean _"it doesn't display the correct image even if the field is not null"_? Are you providing the correct image path?

Comment: I'm calling the image name and path from the database via JSON. The image associated with the record does not show up. Instead the placeholder image appears, even if the Photo field has already been populated.

Comment: Could you update JSBin example with an example of the actual JSON information received from the server? I don't mind if the image shows as a broken link, just want to check if the URL is correctly generated.

Comment: Okay, managed to replicate the issue in the sample. Check it out at http://jsbin.com/iJunOsa/36/edit

Comment: What is the purpose of `if(i+1 === Territories.length)`? I cannot understand it. Also I see that as it is now, you cannot know which image to show. Having more than one entry per Territory, you don't know which image you should display in the tooltip.

Comment: I get your point. That bit of code is to display an array of Territories, and each Territory has its own image. While the list of Territories shows up, the image doesn't.

Comment: You are doing it too complex! Check this: http://jsbin.com/iJunOsa/39/. Works as you expect? If so, I comment what you need to do

Comment: See the full explanation of the proposed solution in the **EDIT** of the answer

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, now I understand what the issue is. Very kind of you to also investigate and find out the exact problem. Much appreciated, have a nice day!